# QA complete (Smart bear) experience

Tags: tools

Has anyone used the test management tool named “QA Complete” (Vendor-Smart bear)? It would be great if any of you can share your experience using QA complete. We are planning on migrating to this tool so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, @ArunJ. Could you please be more specific about the kinds of information you would like? As it stands, this question is likely to get you more opinions than concrete  feedback about possible traps, things the tool does very well and so forth.

Comment: Shouldn't you do research on the product before you switch to it?

Comment: We have done an extensive research and found it to be good. However we would like to hear from someone who has used this tool in the past.